# Should I be content with poster paper or should I try again?

Tags: publications, conference, ieee, poster

A  research paper of mine has been accepted at an IEEE conference.  Although I submitted my best work as a research paper, my best was not  good enough and the reviewers threw it with the poster papers. So, it  will get published in the conference proceeding but will NOT get  uploaded to Xplore Library.

Now  if I go with this, can I try submitting the same paper (as it won't be  online) to other IEEE conferences or reputed journals or do I have to  change it substantially before submitting to other publishers? This  would be a problem because I can not work on it any more without a  top-notch laboratory with chemical equipment; I already did what I  could with just a PC and a lot of time (I am an undergraduate student in a  developing country btw).

Or keeping this in mind, should I simply  withdraw the paper and try elsewhere from scratch?

Comment: Are you sure it's not going to be published on Xplore? For the IEEE conferences I know, also papers presented as posters will be published in just the same way as those presented orally.

Comment: I agree with silvado. In large IEEE conferences in my field, we don't usually have control over poster/oral presentation.  Both are published though. Did you get an acceptance email after the review round? I would slso encourage you to clarify the publishing issue with the TPC chair. Cheers

Comment: The TPC chair clearly mentioned not sending it to Xplore. Now can I publish the same paper later elsewhere? Even if it won't be online, would that interfere with copyright or publication ethics issues?

Comment: If it isn’t officially published online by IEEE, it isn’t in the _de facto_ proceedings. Definitely clarify with the PC chair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraints you name, I would suggest leaving it in the poster session, but attending the conference as mentioned by the answer of [OBu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/120000/75368). If you were a doctoral candidate, rather than an undergraduate, I might suggest differently. But you are at the beginning of your career where any publication is a big plus in moving forward. If you have no way to improve the paper scientifically, then it may be the best outcome for now. But you can leverage the publication for application to a graduate program or employment. Not everyone in your situation will have a publication at all. I think admission committees will look favorably on it. You can reference the conference proceedings, of course.

Moreover, even though you have lost access to your lab, you haven't lost access to what you learned there. I think you are in an excellent position to move forward and that potentially jeopardizing that to seek an even better result is riskier than it needs to be at the moment.

Obviously this is just an opinion for you to consider.

Comment: Thank you for giving the advice I needed. I am inclined towards what you are suggesting. But I am curious about the future of this particular paper. After presenting it, can I submit the same paper to reputed journals? I know that for conference papers it has to contain at least 30% more data for it to be considered by journals. But as my poster paper will not be online, does the same rule apply? Or if it's a little easier as they will not be able to crosscheck it with the present version?

Comment: I doubt that  you can publish it elsewhere. Journals almost always want things that have never appeared. Conference proceedings are a form of publication. In some fields (maybe not yours) they are the most important thing. You have a good conference, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take the chance to visit the conference and discuss your poster content with others. This will give you good feedback and show you how your work is regarded in your field.

Comment: The work is a dead end without sufficient funding and laboratory facilities which nobody has in my country. So the feedback will be useless here. I was hoping for getting abroad to work on this (obviously with a scholarship). That's why I need it to be published as a full paper accessible to admission committee or professors.